# IIS URL Rewrite Query String

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I'm hoping someone will be able to provide some assistance with custom URL rewriting please.

I'm have a URL http://website/central/?agentcontent=about and I'm hoping to Rewrite the URL it looks like http://website/central/about in the URL bar.

Currently my web config looks like :

```
<rule name="Agency Sub Page">
  <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)agentcontent=(.*)" />
       </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}{C:2}" />
</rule>
```

But the nothing happens, url remains the same.

URL Rewrite is definitely installed and working as I have other websites using it with no issues.

Comment: Have a look at the difference between 'rewrite' and 'redirect' in the documentation - http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: I did read through that page already but I'm quite certain im not after a redirect Im after a rewrite. The original link works fine. I only want it to look seo "pretty". Unless your saying I'm completely not understanding the difference between rewrite and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with these rules:

```xml
<rule name="Agency Sub Page with trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="agentcontent=(.*)" />
       </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Agency Sub Page" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="agentcontent=(.*)" />
       </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I used two rules, because of trailing slash at the end (to handle both urls: `http://website/central/?agentcontent=about` and `http://website/central?agentcontent=about`).